# How do I use jQuery when function inside of a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that loops through N number of rows in a table.

```
function runStuff() {
    var databasename = $("#MainContent_ddlTestCaseDB").val();
    var action = $("#MainContent_DropDownList1").val();
    var aPos;
    var aData;
    var caseName;
    var configId;
    var partNumber;
    var runCommand;

    swal({
        title: 'Processing ...',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        showLoaderOnConfrirm: true
    });

    if (action === "ConfigureSelected" || action === "UpdateSelecedCases") {
        $('tr:has(input:checkbox:checked)').each(function () {
            aPos = oTable.row( this ).index();
            aData = oTable.row(aPos).data();

            caseName = aData["CaseName"];
            configId = aData["ConfigId"];
            partNumber = aData["PartNumber"];
            runCommand = action === "ConfigureSelected" ? "B" : "UTC";

            submitRowToBeProcessed("MassReRun", databasename, caseName, configId, partNumber, runCommand);
        });
    }
    else if (action === "RunAll" || action === "UpdateCasesRunAll") {
        $('#tblCases tbody tr').each(function () {

            aPos = oTable.row(this).index();
            aData = oTable.row(aPos).data();

            caseName = aData["CaseName"];
            configId = aData["ConfigId"];
            partNumber = aData["PartNumber"];
            runCommand = action === "RunAll" ? "B" : "UTC";

            submitRowToBeProcessed("MassReRun", databasename, caseName, configId, partNumber, runCommand);

        });
    }

    location.reload();
}
```

This calls a function called submitRowToBeProcessed which does an Ajax call for each row.

```
function submitRowToBeProcessed(action, databasename, caseName, configId, partNumber, runCommand) {
    //$("#loading-indicator-box").show();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.aspx',
        data: { command: action, DatabaseName: databasename, CaseName: caseName, ConfigId: configId, PartNumber: partNumber, RunCommand: runCommand },
        //async: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {

        },
        success: function() {
            //$("#loading-indicator-box").hide();
        }, 
        error: function() {
            //$("#loading-indicator-box").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

I get that I should somehow use the `$when` function to wait for all these ajax requests to complete, but I am not sure how to do that when the number of ajax requests are dynamic.

Ultimately I would like to show a processing message to the end user until all the ajax requests have come back. Even better if I could get that message to update on progress 1 of row count processing 2 or row count processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear how your code is structured, but potentially, you can store all your AJAX requests in an array, then use [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) on the [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) function to determine when all requests are complete.

The first thing you will do is to return your AJAX [Promise](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) from your `submitRowToBeProcessed()` function:

```
function submitRowToBeProcessed() {
  return $.ajax({...}); //fill your own settings
}
```

Then before your loop define an array to store your requests, and a counter of how many requests are in progress.

```
var requests = [];
var inProgressCount = 0;
```

Inside your loop you will add a class to the row which will indicate to the user. You will store the AJAX promise to be used in two separate ways: once when the one request is complete to remove the "processing" class, and once to add to the collection of outstanding requests.

```
$('tr:has(input:checkbox:checked)').each(function () {
  //store a reference
  var row = $(this);

  //show row as being processed
  row.addClass("processing");

  //submit ajax request
  var ajax = submitRowToBeProcessed("MassReRun", databasename, caseName, configId, partNumber, runCommand);

  //increment counter
  inProgressCount++;

  //store promise for later
  requests.push(ajax);

  ajax.then(function() {
    //this row's ajax call is complete
    row.removeClass("processing");

    //decrement counter, potentially show this number to the user
    inProgressCount--;
  });

});
```

Now, at end of your loop do something like the following:

```
$.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {
  alert("All AJAX is complete!");
});
```

Comment: Maybe i should post a separate question. Essentially think of each row of a table as an ajax request. I would like to show each row in that table as processing until its respective ajax call completes. Each ajax call can take several seconds and i could have thousands of rows. What you provided here will get me part of it by showing the user when all those thousands of rows have completed.

Comment: That's just a small change. I updated the answer to show how you can do that. Basically just add a class to the row that will indicate to the user that the request is processing, and clear that class when the request is complete. You can even keep track of how many requests are in progress. At the end you can still use the request array to determine when all requests are complete.